# Is this rudbeckia?

Tags: identification, perennials

This perennial is sold to me as rudbeckia. It is similar to my other yellow rudbeckia, but the petals (apart having different color) are much finer while touching. Is this really rudbeckia?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I believe it is a Rudbeckia variety - the colours look a bit drab in your photo, but it might be Rudbeckia hirta 'Summerina orange'. There a lot more hybrids and varieties these days which don't immediately look like Rudbeckia https://www.dreamstime.com/stock-photo-rudbeckia-hirta-summerina-orange-red-orange-flowers-image95921005. This plant prefers full sun, but does not like soil which dries out frequently, so dampish soil and sunlight (not an easy combination).

Comment: Are those cultivars shorter lived compared to regular rudbeckia?

Comment: Not so far as I'm aware - most loss of these plants is attributable to dry soil in my experience. You might find some colour change in the flowers over the years, that sometimes happens.